# Tyring to pivot based on Date field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 fields that I want to pull into a query, plus a deal_balance (Decimal), and AsOfDate (Date).  I tried two different ways; neither worked but I think both are close.  The only catch is that the AsOfDate is the last working day of each month.  I'm not sure how to convert that into an Integer (1,2,etc) or an abbreviated month's name (Jan,Feb,etc.)

```
select Contact_ID, TB_Line,
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 1 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthJan,
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 2 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthFeb,
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 3 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthMar,  
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 4 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthApr,
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 5 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthMay,
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 6 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthJun,
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 7 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthJul,
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 8 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthAug,
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 9 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthSep,
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 10 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthOct,
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 11 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthNov,
  sum(case when [AsOfDate] = 12 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthDec
from [TBL_HIST]
group by Contact_ID, TB_Line;


SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT Contact_ID, TB_Line, AsOfDate, Deal_Balance
  FROM [TBL_HIST]
) src
pivot
(
  SUM(DEAL_BALANCE)
  for AsOfDate in (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec)
) piv;
```

I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the `month()` function:

```
select Contact_ID, TB_Line,
       sum(case when month([AsOfDate]) = 1 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthJan,
       sum(case when month([AsOfDate]0 = 2 then [DEAL_BALANCE] else 0 end) MonthFeb,
       . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got the other version working!!

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT Contact_ID, TB_Line, Deal_Balance, DATENAME(Month,[AsOfDate]) AS TheDate
  FROM [TBL_HIST]
) AS P
PIVOT
(
  SUM(DEAL_BALANCE) for TheDate in (January, February, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December)
) AS PV;
```